# EBNF used in datatable.select(filter_condition)

Tags: .net, datatable, ebnf

Does anyone know what EBNF is used in Datatable.Select(filter_condition)? What I'm trying to achieve is to highlight statements similar to the SQL-WHERE part.

Comment: This is somewhat discouraging: the [docs from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) describe the syntax in English narrative, rather than formally.